Style.css file name is missing from HMTL in Wordpress theme
Hopefully some of you can assist me a bit. I don't have clue why the wordpress theme output is not including style.css. There is only correct path to theme directory but style.css is missing "...themes/wp-test-theme?ver=6.7.1"
functions.php
function my_theme_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'style-own', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(  ) );

}
add_action(  'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_scripts' );
OUTPUT
link rel="stylesheet" id="style-own-css" href="http://localhost/wp-test/wp-content/themes/wp-test-theme?ver=6.7.1" type="text/css" media="all">

try this.
To include style.css, you need to specify its full path.
functions.php
function my_theme_scripts() {
   
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-own', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_scripts' );


I have understood that style.css can left out and I have also an other theme where style.css is there in output even if it's not defined in functions.php.

You can use the following code:
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );


try this code.
You Enqueue Parent and Child Theme Styles Below Code Use 'functions.php' file:
function my_child_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    // Enqueue Parent Theme Style
    wp_enqueue_style('parent-theme-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    
    // Enqueue Child Theme Style (after Parent Style)
    wp_enqueue_style('child-theme-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('parent-theme-style'), wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_child_theme_enqueue_styles');

